# Why does a SqlException thrown by SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery contain all the PRINTs as errors?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sqlcommand, sqlexception

When I run the following snippet

```
try
{
 using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("I'm shy"))
 {
  conn.Open();

  using (SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand())
  {
   cmd.CommandText = "PRINT 'A';PRINT 'B';PRINT 'C';RAISERROR('SQL_Error', 18, 1)";
   cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
  }
 }
}
catch (SqlException ex)
{
 MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

I get the following message:

```
SQL_Error
A
B
C
```

and `ex.Errors` has 4 entries (The 3 `SqlError`'s corresponding to the prints have a `SqlError.Class` of 0 (vs. 18 for the real error)

However, if I replace `ExecuteNonQuery` with `ExecuteScalar`, I get the expected result:

The message is `SQL_Error` and I only have one entry in `ex.Errors`...

Is there any way to avoid the strange behavior of `cmd.ExecuteNonQuery`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't avoid this behavior. Its the result of the way  TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning() is written

particularly this line

```
  bool breakConnection = this.AddSqlErrorToCollection(ref temp, ref this._errors) | this.AddSqlErrorToCollection(ref temp, ref this._attentionErrors);
        breakConnection |= this.AddSqlErrorToCollection(ref temp, ref this._warnings);
        breakConnection |= this.AddSqlErrorToCollection(ref temp, ref this._attentionWarnings);
```

My guess is that for whatever reason one of the collection _error or _attentionErrors is empty for ExecuteScaler and its not for ExecuteNonQuery.

I'm sure if you poked around enough you could probably find out why.

In any case you seem to have the workaround already. Only use the first item in   SQLExecption.Error

Answer (score 0):

ExecuteNonQuery normally returns a recordset while ExecuteScalar returns the first row + first column.

Comment: WExecuteNonQuery returns the number of rows affected (similar to @@ROWCOUNT) and it has some perks with the -1 return value. ExecuteReader returns a SqlDataReader. You are right for the ExecuteScalar though.